# rabbitmq with custom ordering based on an attribute

Tags: java, rabbitmq

We did an R&D for a basic rabbit mq queue with confirms. We now want to go a step further and split channels by username using something like a routing key. (https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html).

However we have a requirement to use custom ordering per user, the json that we are getting from upstream has a parameter called `sequence`. The service that pushes data to rabbitmq might get the first json from upstream with a sequence number of `2` and afterwards get `1`. Is there a way of pushing the json with the `seuqence` number `2` to the queue but only have it delivered after the queue recieved the json with `1` and delivered it.

Basically what we are wondering is whether there is a way to use custom ordering on rabbitmq for message delivery based on this `sequence` parameter without the need to have a separate service to maintain this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically what we are wondering is whether there is a way to use custom ordering on rabbitmq for message delivery based on this sequence parameter without the need to have a separate service to maintain this order.

No. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html :

> From RabbitMQ release 2.7.0, messages are always held in the queue in publication order, even in the presence of requeueing or channel closure.

So it appears there is not easy support for your usecase.

Of course, if you are really want re-queueing (and you do not want to keep messages at your consumer) you could implement something like this pseudocode for your consumer:

```
expected_message_id = 0
while (true) {
    m = receive_message(queue)
    if (m.id == expected_message_id) {
        process(m)
        m.acknowledge()
        expected_message_id++
    } else {
        republish_to_queue(m, queue) // might use old exchange, or pick a new-one for this type of back-channel
    }
}
```

Obviously, this means extra network/processing load for you - the message might be delivered and thrown away multiple times.

Comment: A bit off topic but do you know if there are any other queue products out there that would support this, also would you recommend breaking the queues up using the username parameter in the service to reduce the number of queue exchanges